# Is that possible to draw a line using Openscad by joining different points?

Tags: 3d, 3d-modelling, openscad, openjscad

I'm trying regularly to join the different points to draw the **straight line** in **OpenScad**. But I could'nt able to find any way to draw the line. But I can able to draw the definite shapes like cubes,spheres,cylinders,etc... So please help me by directing to get into the correct **program coding** to draw the straight lines by joining the different points.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers. You can use this [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) in order to make sure your question is not missing anything important.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OpenSCAD currently doesn't have a line primitive; all primitives have to be closed volumes or closed polygons.
You can simulate a "line" in space by using hull(), and even package that as a module:

```
module line(start, end, thickness = 1) {
    hull() {
        translate(start) sphere(thickness);
        translate(end) sphere(thickness);
    }
}

line([0,0,0], [5,23,42]);
```

Comment: Or the better approach from the manual to draw a cylinder between two points: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Tips_and_Tricks#Drawing_%22lines%22_in_OpenSCAD

Comment: While drawing a cylinder is okay for a 3d shape, for a 2D one, you can draw a "square" between two points, by giving a vector for its size.